# How to filter table records in DMS migration task using wildcard

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-dms

In my DMS migration task, I want to filter table records based on column value. However I need to use a wildcard. In example below I want to skip all the records from a table `data` where field `description` contains text "test".

Is it possible to get a wildcard type of behavior in DMS migration task's column filter in table mappings? I tried using `%` wildcard but it doesn't work see console and JSON below:

[image]

```
{
  "rule-type": "selection",
  "rule-id": "123456789",
  "rule-name": "123456789",
  "object-locator": {
    "schema-name": "dbo",
    "table-name": "data"
  },
  "rule-action": "include",
  "filters": [
    {
      "filter-type": "source",
      "column-name": "description",
      "filter-conditions": [
        {
          "filter-operator": "noteq",
          "value": "%test%"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

So I'm wondering if there is a way to implement this behavior in any way in migration task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The wildcards work for schema and table names. There are no [filter operators](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Tasks.CustomizingTasks.Filters.html) such as "like" for DMS table mapping where wildcards can be used.

If it is an option for you, you could filter any other column for the exact value or add a column on the source table which you can use it for filter during migration.